# Resolver for spring-data-neo4j

Tags: scala, playframework, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to use spring-data-neo4j with play framework 2.6 in Scala. But when I add the library dependency I have a compilation error:

object neo4j is not a member of package org

for

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.{GraphId, NodeEntity}
```

I think I don't have good resolvers:

```
name := """Project-name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.0" % Test,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.194",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "4.2.6.RELEASE"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes you are trying to import `import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.{GraphId, NodeEntity}` is part of `neo4j-ogm-core` artifact. so you must include it as shown below to able to access those classes.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-ogm-core" % "3.0.0-RC1"
```

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: did you add the above entry in your sbt file and restarted the sbt console?

Comment: `neo4j-ogm-core` is a transitive dependency of spring-data-neo4j, so @Mickael.w should get it through that.